# How does jupyterhub work?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have to construct the infrastructure so that multiple users can work on the same jupyter(ipython notebook) service, yet via different sessions, so the users can't interrupt each other.
I thought jupyterhub( https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub) is there to control everything, yet it still seems like the session is bound to one since if I logout of it on one window, an instance on another window also logs out.
Is there a way to control multi-sessions on jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter doesn't support multiple users editing the same notebook at the same time without data loss. I don't believe it is meant to. I believe Jupyter is meant to provide a relatively easy to configure and install instance of python that contains the same installed modules and environment to minimize problems caused by environmental differences between developer workstations.

Also, it's meant to make the barrier for entry to programming python and working in data science much lower than it otherwise would be. That is, it's much easier to talk an analyst into visiting a website than learning a new programming language.

More to the point of your question, though: The way Jupyter handles 'sessions' is that (unless configured otherwise), every Jupyter user corresponds to a user on the on the server that is running Jupyter and every time you log in to Jupyter you are effectively creating a new login to that server's operating system. It immediately follows that if you log out of Jupyter from one window, you're logging out of not just that browser's session, but also the login to the Jupyter server's operating system as well, which would kill all other open browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear, JupyterHub is meant to support multi-user across many machines. If course if you use the same browser from the same machine, you get logged out too, as the browser is carrying the connexion information that get revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyterhub is a web based multiuser application, that provides session and authentication services.
Jupyterhub will be hosted in unix/linux server, the client can access it using the ip address and port number,Once it is accessed by client, the client must enter the userid and password which is associated with the sytem users in server (PAM authentication) which will redirect to the home directory of the current user.
You can build a infrastructure by using jupyterhub, which is meant for multi-user. The jupyterhub just provides multi user interface and PAM authentication, you have to configure security, file access permission everything in kernel level using shell script.
Normally, you host a jupyterhub or jupyter notebook in command line. In the same way you can write a shell script to setup multi-user environment.